# how to use drawViewHierarchyInRect

Tags: ios

I want to create a snapshot image for a UIView, I used to use renderInRect, but it is slow, and I found that drawViewHierarchyInRect is a newer API since iOS 7, so I want to try it.

I write below code, but it never create a valid image, just a blank image.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_mapView.bounds.size, _mapView.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Used to use renderInContext, but it's slow
    // [mapView.layer renderInContext:context];

    [_mapView drawViewHierarchyInRect:_mapView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.thumbImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self addSubview:self.thumbImageView];
}
```

Comment: Maybe your mapView is invisible (not in the View Hierarchy)

Comment: Do I have to add mapView into view hierarchy? This is exactly what I am avoiding to, because I don't want to draw it, just want a image. `renderInContext` can do the work without adding it into view hierarchy, are sure about `drawViewHierarchyInRect`?

Answer (score 1):

The `-drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:`, which lets you render a ***snapshot*** of the complete view hierarchy as visible onscreen into a bitmap context.

`renderInContext:` renders directly from a CALayer's render tree to valid Core Graphics context.

If you want to render the view to a UIImage rather than having it on the View Hierarchy, you should using `renderInContext`.

Comment: well, could you explain, if I use `UIView *view = [_mapView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];` to replace `drawViewHierarchyInRect`, I still does not add it into view hierarchy, but I do get a valid UIView, though it is not an image. I am confused, are they not working in same way?